# Функция + событие, вернуть результат этого вызова

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток!

Пишу функцию получения текущей ссылки и её названия в chrome.

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
                                      return tab.url;
                                     }
                      );
```

Вот так это и выглядит. Внутри getCurrent вызывается обратный вызов, куда передаётся текущаяя вкладка хрома.

Мне надо как-то так:

```
function GetCurrentURL() {

     return chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
                                              return tab.url;
                                             }
                              );
    };
```

в return от GetCurrentURL получить tab.url.

Как этого добиться?

Answer (score 4):

Особо никак, тут событийная модель используется. Вызов chrome.tabs.getCurrent асинхронный, поэтому подождать его результата внутри GetCurrentURL не получится. Единственное, что вам остается, это передавать в GetCurrentURL callback, который будет принимать результат. Вроде того:

```
function GetCurrentURL(callback) {
  chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) { callback(tab.url); } );
}

GetCurrentURL(function(url) { alert(url); });
```

Comment: Попробовал. выбивает: Error in response to tabs.getCurrent: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

<pre><code>function GetCurrentURL(callback) {
 chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function (tab) {
  callback(tab.url)
 });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', $(function () {
  var s;
  GetCurrentURL(function (s) {
   alert(s)
  });
</code></pre>
tabs прописан в premissions.

Comment: Я если честно этот API не очень знаю, в документации написано, что этот метод работает только если вызван из вкладки (т.е. насколько я понимаю это должен быть injected код).

Answer (score 1):

Создаем background скрипт, согласно документации. 
Там используем событие chrome.tabs.onActivated чтобы получать нужную информацию, и храним её где-нибудь там же.

Используем так:
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().<глобальная переменная, в которой что-то сохранили>